# Cuál sería el uso de un método estático en una clase normal

Tags: c#

Si tengo un método estático en una clase normal, cuál seria su función. Tengo entendido que los atributos estáticos en una clase normal comparten el mismo dato en todos los objetos que se crean (LO SAQUE DE ESTA FUENTE: [enlace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SlvjhkKxgo)). Pero cuál seria la función de los métodos estáticos.

**Atributo estático**

```
class MiClase
{
    private static int numero = 0;

    public int CambiarNumero(int num)
    {
        numero = num;
    }
}

class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MiClase mc1 = new MiClase();
            MiClase mc2 = new MiClase();
            MiClase mc3 = new MiClase();

            mc1.CambiarNumero(2);
            mc2.CambiarNumero(1);
            mc3.CambiarNumero(6);
            //AL FINAL SI IMPRIMIMOS ESTOS 3 MÉTODOS EL VALOR DE LA VARIABLE 
            //"numero" SERÁ 6 YA QUE ESA ATRIBUTO ES ESTÁTICO Y LO COMPARTE 
            //CON OTROS OBJETOS. ¿Y CÓMO SERÍA PARA LOS MÉTODOS?

        }
}
```

//Método Estático

```
public class MiClase
{
    public static string nombre()
    {
        return "Franco";
    }

    public static int numero = 0;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = MiClase.numero; //SI ACCEDE
        string nom = MiClase.nombre(); //NO ACCEDE
    }
}
```

Comment: El metodo o clase static se crean cuando el programa inicia y no hace falta instanciarlo para acceder a su propiedad o resultado, por lo tanto esta siempre disponible el valor que le pases.

Comment: @RamiroBarone y cómo puedo acceder a estos métodos estaticos, supongamos que la clase NO es estática pero algunos métodos SI, ¿cómo podría acceder a estos?

Comment: Estoy que intento acceder al colocar el punto, pero no sale el nombre de mi método

Comment: Fijate que tu clase o metodo sean estaticos y que sean publicos ambos para que este visibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los metodos estaticos funcionan como si tuvieras un objeto global. No necesitas crear un objeto para ocuparlo.

Por ejemplo,

```
using System;

public class Math
{
    public static int Max(int a, int b)
    {
       if (a < b)
          return b;

       return a;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int max = Math.Max(1, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

[Prueba este código aquí](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUH1AZgAINiBZAQ2AAs8BvPY50k1TANmIEspgLKADwAUvfpRg8+xAEYBKJi0a4Wq7gDNiwysQA8shStXHUAdlkBuPIpPnKVo8wC+eF/lxFS6UplMMbXugBysYsYsQAtkLEALwCtAB0VCKYkuhyDqHM7ACcwlGCGQFuTkA)

Comment: Hola @CristobalMontecino, estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo que tu en mi código y no me aparece el metodo para que pueda usarlo. ¿Haz agregado algo más aparte?

Comment: Sí, debes agregarle public. También, si esta en otro archivo, debes usar using.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi pregunta, asi lo estoy haciendo

Comment: Ya puse public la clase "MiClase", "Program", "Main", el atributo y método, pero aún así NO logro acceder.

Comment: Lo probé y sí funciona. Quizá no estoy entendiendo a que te refieres con acceder.

Comment: En el ejemplo que me mostraste tienes el método "Max" a la cual estas ingresando, yo tengo mi método "nombre" a la cuál no puedo ingresar

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104726/discussion-between-cristobal-montecino-and-gian-franco-alexis-poma-vidal).

Comment: YA ME SALIO!!!, no me aparecía el nombre al colocar el punto, pero tipie el nombre del metodo y salio.

Comment: que raro, pero tu respuesta me ha ayudado bastante, gracias, ahora coloco tu respuesta como la ganadora.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar el patron de diseño singleton para profundizar más.

Comment: gracias @CristobalMontecino ;)

Answer (score 1):

Un metodo `static` se aplica cuando quiere realizar codigo que no aplica al contexto de la instancia de la clase, por instancia me refiero a usar el `new` con un `class`

Podrias leer

[Clases estáticas y sus miembros (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Seria algo como esto

```
public class MiClase
{
    public static int CambiarNumero(int num)
    {
        return num;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int nro = 0;

        nro = MiClase.CambiarNumero(2);
        nro = MiClase.CambiarNumero(1);
        nro = MiClase.CambiarNumero(6);
    }
}
```

como veras aqui si usas el `return` del metodo porque alteras la variable que pisas en cada ejecucion, al final `nro` tendra el valor de `6`